# Swift 3 - Changing map Type from a view controller to another

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am working in Xcode 8 - Swift.
I have 2 viewcontrollers: MAin Screen (first) and View Options (Second ViewController). 
In the Main Screen I have a map with my location. In this screen I have a button so that the user can go to Views Screen and select what type o map he wants (this is done by a segue). The user can choose from three options: Normal, Satellite and Terrain. I implemented the second view controller has a table view of buttons. Whatever I choose it sends me to the home screen (first view controller).
I dont have another segue to send me to first view controller has I implemented a navigation controller with back buckon.

Tested this so far. Everything working ok : maps, and other things.

I created a protocol/delegate so that, when I choose what type of map I want to see in the first view controller, it sends me the information to the first. I tried send a string from the first view controller to the second and a managed to do that.
The thing is, I cannot change the map type... I dont know why but it was shows me the standard map...

Can anyone help me please?

Here is a sample of me code. Main Screen First View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, DataSentDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()      

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest   
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true          
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let longDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() 
}

//Protocol
func userSentView(data: String) {


    switch (data) {

    case "Satellite":
        self.map.mapType = .satellite
        break

    case "Terrain":
        self.map.mapType = .hybrid
        break


    default:
        self.map.mapType = .standard
        break  
    }

}

//Protocol
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueView" {
        let TVCView: TVCView = segue.destination as! TVCView
        TVCView.delegate = self
    }
}

 }
```

---

In the second viewcontroller I have this:

---

```
protocol DataSentDelegate {
func userSentView(data: String)
}


class TVCView: UITableViewController {

var ViewNames = [String]()
var identities = [String]()

//***
var delegate: DataSentDelegate? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "View"

    //globalView = 1;

    ViewNames = ["Normal","Satellite","Terrain"]
    identities = ["Normal","Satellite","Terrain"]

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ViewNames.count
}


//Add names to cells

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellView", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = ViewNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)


    //To know which view was selected

    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]

    //***
    if delegate != nil {

        let data = vcName
        delegate?.userSentView(data: data)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



}




}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `switch (data)` in `userSentView(data:)` to check, if the method is called. And btw: You don't need to check if `delegate` is nil. This is done by the `?` operator in `delegate?.userSentView(data: data)`

Comment: I've removed the "check if delegate is nil". And I tried the break point and the method is called. When I tried option 3 (terrain) I got this:  dat = (string) "Terrain"   self= (xxx.viewcontroller)0x7b9b81d0   _0(1tring)  _1(String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are pushing on a whole new (Home) `ViewController` rather than popping off the stack to the existing one.

You should remove these lines:

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
```

And replace this line:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with:

```
let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: You're welcome! I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks!